# (1/1) ErrorException Undefined index: id in ClientController.php (line 81)

Tags: php, api, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I am not sure why  I am getting this error.  Here is the method in the ClientController.

```
protected function updateOneStudent($parameters)
{
  $studentId = $parameters['id'];
  return $this-  >performPutRequest("https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students/{$studentId}", $parameters);
}
```

Basically I am trying to update a selected student.  Below is the update form.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

 @section('content')
 <form action="{{url('/student/update')}}" method="POST" role="form">
     {{ csrf_field() }}

{{method_field('PUT')}}
<legend>Create a Student</legend>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$student->name }}"required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Address</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{{$student->address }}" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{$student->phone }}" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Career</label>
  <select name="career" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option>Select a Career</option>
    <option value="math"{{$student->career == 'math' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Math</option>
    <option value="physics"{{$student->career == 'physics' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Physics</option>
    <option value="engineering"{{$student->career == '' ? 'engineering' : ''}}>Engineering</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Student</button>
</form>

  @endsection
```

Comment: What does "(1/1)" refer to?

Comment: It what comes up in the Laravel error page.

Comment: I think it is just a mistake but have you seen  "return $this-  >performPutRequest("https://lumenapi.juandmegon.com/students/{$studentId}", $parameters);" arrow is separated?

Comment: And what is `$parameters`?

Comment: `if (! isset($parameters['id'])) throw new \Exception('Well that won't work');` It's like the error is telling you what is wrong ;)

Comment: where do I put that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: I have done a dd($parameters) and I am getting an empty array.  Does this help.

Answer (score 1):

The request I was sending was wrong. The error was in the StudentController.
I had

```
public function getUpdateStudent()
{
  $students = $this->obtainAllStudents;
  return view('students.select-student', ['students'=> $students]);
}
```

It it should have been

```
public function getUpdateStudent()
{
  $students = $this->obtainAllStudents();
  return view('students.select-student', ['students'=> $students]);
}
```

I missed the brackets to call the getUpdateStudent.  Sorry guys I did not show this code earlier.